# Use URL Query String to Authenticate in PHP

Tags: php, session, query-string

Normally When I design a site that allow users to login, I create session variables of the user info from the database and ensure that at least one of the session variable is available on each page of the site, else the user would be redirected to the login page like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  header("Location:login.php");
}
```

But then I've been thinking lately, instead of using session variables to authenticate users, why not use the query string. My idea is to create a unique string which is based on some factors, like `date(month, year, day)` or `access time(day, hour)` or `ip address`, and maybe `hash` it using `md5` so the url might look like this

`://mysite.com/dashboard?auth=12jsdnnau819wiskj3jdnck23ksj12j3`.

So now I can easily logout a user if he has not accessed the site for more than one hour or more than one day. But I do not know if this is a good idea, that is why i am here, to seek for advice on a better way to go. Thanks all.

Comment: And why not just store the access timestamp as a session variable?

Comment: Why not use session expiration policy? Internally, a web session is maintained in a similar fashion - either by a session id passed to the request, or a session cookie stored in a browser

Comment: No, it’s not a good idea. And what does this have to do with logging the user out?

Comment: That would work, but it would be just as easy to store this data in a cookie. And by not cluttering your URLs with variable query strings, you'll make your site friendlier to search engines.

Comment: In addition, session is limited to a single browser, a url can extend the session among different browsers and computers, which is not OK. If you sent your auth url to a friend, say, via Skype, the s/he will be logged with your account

Comment: timestamp? expiration Policy? I have never worked with those before realy

Comment: without storing some data into the session, you allow someone else to steel the token and access to the user account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because URLs:

- Leak easily
- Get bookmarked
- Don't carry their data over automatically when the user opens a new tab and navigates back to the site

and because nothing is stopping you from storing the same data in a session and using that to easily logout a user so it doesn't even *add* the one benefit you highlight.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

Do you remember the days when PHP session ID could be stored in the URL, and you would have URLs that look like: `index.php?PHPSESSID=....` ?

We have moved away from this to more secure implementations, user friendly URLs, etc.

Just as a simple example of what can go wrong: A web crawler can crawl your website, and if reaching the admin panel with a properly authenticated URL (as you described), it could become publicly available to ... anyone.

So ... don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few reasons **not** to do this:

- The hashed request parameter is **publicly visible**. This means anyone using that url will be considered an authenticated user.
- As I can see, the token is per user, so all requests using this token will be done on behalf the same user. If you share a url, anyone using that url will impersonate the same user, and have all the access rights granted to that user.
- Other answers have mentioned that the urls can easly leak, or be bookmarked. In addition to their points, once the token expires, the url may become broken, if you trigger a login or other authentication redirect mechanism.
- A pure technical drawback of your idea is also this: you need to persist the token when navigating across different pages in your app

The HTTP Session has been designed to serve this purpose and at the same time be safe enough. The application session length can be tuned so that it matches your requirement. I recommend you to get familiar on how HTTP sessions work and how to tune your session expiration policy, rather than compromise your application's security